# Missing files and folders when downloading Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, 19.04

I have downloaded both Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04 and I am faced with the same issue in both cases.
It appears I miss some folders and files in order to be able to install Ubuntu on my laptop. I am adding a screenshot of what I get and if I compare it to what I should have according to Ubuntu, you can see what I mean.
I have burnt a dvd with the files I got (18.04), made sure the laptop set up are correct for the installation to occur from the dvd, etc, but nothing happens...
Maybe this is very easy to solve but I am not a big computer geek so if you can help me with the simplest explanation, I really would appreciate it. I am fed up with Windows and I want to switch to Ubuntu.
Thanks in advance. :)[Ubuntu files and folders I get when extracting 19.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPm2D.jpg)
[Correct diagram screenshoted from the Ubuntu site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkbft.jpg)

Comment: Looks OK to me. What do you think you are missing? What happens when you boot from the DVD?

Comment: welcome to linux ... those are system dirs/files you can ignore ... any boot-able box will have an EFI dir possibly in a different partition

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for your fast replies @Jos ..
I have added to my previous message a screenshot from the Ubuntu site showing what should be in the download. When I boot from the DVD, nothing happens at all. That diagram makes me think I am missing the Bin and the Program folders along with a series of files susch as the Start.exe... I am so puzzled. :)
:/

Comment: and @Scott Stensland my previous comment is also to thank you :)
Do you mean I don´t need those folders?

Comment: those are system files which you need

Comment: mmmh, ok... Thanks so much again for your quick response. :)

Comment: How do you burn the files to the DVD? Describe what you do, and include screenshots.

Comment: @vidarlo, Hello, I think you are on the right track. I am actually reburning the DVD. This might well be the cause of my issue. Will inform you on the results.

Comment: *How* are you burning in it? You should burn it as an iso image. No extraction or anything. You can follow [this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows) for how to do it.

Comment: You were right!  I didn't burn the iso correctly. I managed to install it however I am now facing another issue so I am reinstalling it. thanks soo much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the boot order to boot from media first (before the hard drive), then see what it does. Those folders look correct.

If you can, download the iso again and try installing from usb. [These instructions are for doing so in Windows.](https://tecadmin.net/create-ubuntu-bootable-usb-in-windows/)

If you prefer DVD, try making a new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! The boot order is correct. I have double and triple checked with a friend this. Good to know I have the correct files although I am not sure why it shows differently on the ubuntu site.

Comment: I edited my answer to suggest instructions for installing from usb. Can you redownload the iso and try that?

Comment: Just saying - installing from USB or optical drive is by default disabled on some uefi systems and you have to expressly allow it.  I suspect this is the case in this instance where optical drive is not considered a valid target for a UEFI installation.

Comment: That's a good point. In the UEFI menus look for any options that look related to controlling booting options and try it with them off. Also, try turning secure boot off. When you say nothing happens do you mean Windows just starts?

Comment: @RobotHumans, Hi! Thanks for your reply. I am actually now burning another DVD. I think I did it wrong and might be the cause of my issue. Will let you know! :)

Comment: @partial_mask Thanks a lot for your help. I burnt a new DVD and ran it. It is now working. I have Ubuntu. I now need to find some help to fix sound issue.
Thanks a lot everyone for their contribution and time! All the best!

Comment: if my answer helped you can accept it with the check mark on the left. Glad you got it working and welcome to Linux :-)